# FreeBSD - Change user password after SSHing into a Server

Tags: ssh, security, freebsd, pam, passwd

I would like to change the user password after having SSHed into a server, but get the following error:

> passwd
>   Changing local password for 
>   **passwd: pam_start(): System error**

What is the reason for this and how can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Perhaps you are not providing a pty. Add your ssh command to your post.

Comment: Is the db corrupt? Check using `pwd_mkdb -C /etc/master.passwd`. See [pwd_mkdb](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=pwd_mkdb&sektion=8&n=1)